# Trouble Canon MG5522 printer (Not Listed in system settings)

Tags: canon

Trying to install a Canon MG5522 printer. 
* I'm running Ubuntu 13.10
* Here's what I am doing:
-> System Settings
-> Printer

Comment: and then what happens?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Your question got cut off.  [Edit] your question again and fill out the rest!